# after installation of simple qrcode, blade engine doesnt work on laravel5

Tags: laravel

After installing illuminate/html, my blade engine was wrrking well. But when I installed simple qrCode via:

```
"require": {
    "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "~1"
}
```

I get this error:

```
Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found
```

the output of terminal after installation, simple qrcode was:

```
Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/usr/bin/composer self-update" to get the latest version.
Key require is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line 53
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing illuminate/html (v5.0.0)
  - Installing bacon/bacon-qr-code (1.0.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode (1.4.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in /home/farhad/public_html/letterPanel/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146

                                                           
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found    
                                                           

Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error


                                                                                                                                                     
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                 
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in /home/farhad/public_html/letterPanel/laravel/vendor/lara  
  vel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146
```

I also ran `composer require illuminate/html` after this error. But I get that same error.

Comment: Is it in your app config file?

Comment: yes,
Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class 
,\and facade also.

Comment: Correct this too: `Key require is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line 53`

Comment: sorry to say that.but where is the line 53. i cant understand!

Comment: You can't see line 53 in composer.json? You basically have require twice and you shouldn't. Edit your question with the contents of composer.json and we will try our best to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `composer.json` file has two `require` keys, as mentioned in the composer error in your question:

> Key require is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line 53

Remove to have a correctly formed composer.json file and retry.

Answer (score 1):

You're installing module for Laravel 4 on Laravel 5 project. Html package was removed from Laravel 5.

You can look for another package or you could [install Html package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) and adapt qrcode to work with Laravel 5.

Comment: in this link, it said we can use on laravel 5.please see configuration segment:
https://www.simplesoftware.io/docs/simple-qrcode

Comment: I didn't find any code that tried to use Html package inside qrcode package. It seems the error caused by another package, installed on the same Laravel project.

Comment: thanks in advance, you are right. i used require two times.so the first require in composer.json installed illuminate/html, and in second one, we unistall it(beacuse in second 'required' i dont have illuminate/html.
 so composer unistalled it.

Answer (score 0):

The line "simpleoftwareio / simple-qrcode": "~ 1" must be within "require" that is already in your composer.json.